# QGIS Output Command Line Results on the Terminal

Tags: qgis, windows, command-line

QGIS as a command line mode with limited fonctionnality.

*The following code examples use QGIS 3.14 on Windows 10*

For example to access QGIS version number, you can type:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis-bin --version
```

It's working... But it displays nothing on the terminal...

To display something once can use

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis --version | more
```

With the answer on the terminal:

```
QGIS 3.14.0-Pi 'Pi' (9f7028fd23)
```

Or redirect the StdOut and StrErr to a file

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\qgis --version > stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt
```

which is working but annoying...

Is there a clean way to make QGIS display the results on the terminal.

Note: The QGIS command line mode will be much more used in the coming years with the addition in 3.14 of a new command line mode to use QGIS processing algorithms in batch mode, it's called qgis_process. [See QGIS 3.14 change log](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog314/index.html).  It is working well but behave the same as what is described above in terms of StdOut and StdErr redirection.

Comment: `python3 -c "from qgis.core import Qgis; print(Qgis.version())"` :) (not more simple, just an alternative in fact)

Comment: IMHO, ask the "why" they choose to use this particular "StdOut and STdErr redirection" behavior on the QGIS issue tracker https://github.com/qgis/qgis/issues/

Comment: To place a question on the QGIS issue tracker was in my mind.  I wanted to touch base with the community before placing an issue on GitHub.

Comment: I let other answers. Also curious. Maybe a QGIS code contributor will come :)

Comment: Weird. BTW I tried `> con` which also doesn't work.

Comment: I posted an issue on QGIS: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37465

Answer (score 0):

[Isssue posted](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/37465#event-3527211810) on QGIS issues has been solved and closed. Next QGIS release should contain the correction.